# If java used interpreter for .class file and compiler for machine level code what would be the prob?

Tags: java

why java uses both interpreter and compiler

Comment: Read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)#Java_Virtual_Machine

Comment: Please could you take some time to rewrite your question to make it clearer? I, for one, don't really understand what's being asked.

Answer (score 1):

> why java uses both interpreter and compiler

To be platform independent.

Compiler generates a machine independent code. that can be interpreted by different machine dependent compilers in their own way. i.e. a java program compiled on one machine can be run of different machines having different Processor, OS etc.

> If java used interpreter for .class file and compiler for machine level code what would be the prob?

Compiler generated `.class` file that is called `bytecode`. This `bytecode` is read by `JIT` and gets executed on JVM.

That's how they have designed it. probably makes it easier for the programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the biggest difference is that languages like Python, or Ruby that are solely interpreted have poorer performance. Java gets better performance because of the compilation.